# Como consultar disponibilidad por fechas?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, estoy trabajando con un calendario y tengo esta relacion entre tablas
[image: Tablas involucradas]

Lo que quiero es saber si el evento que estoy ingresando puede contar con el responsable que estoy eligiendo para el, ya que puede que este responsable ya tiene un evento para la fecha que se quiere ingresar. La consulta es lo que no tengo muy claro, se que puedo hacer un between pero no me queda del todo claro, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esta instrucción Sql vas a saber, si el responsable, tiene un evento asignado en la fecha que consultes. Los parametros que debes proveer son idreponsable y la fecha a consultar:

```
select re.nombre, ev.start, ev.end, ev.description 
     from events ev inner join responsable re 
       on ev.idresponsable = re.idresponsable
     where  param_idresponsable  = ev.idresponsable and 
                  param_fecha  between ev.start and ev.end ;
```

Comment: Patric con **con_fecha** a que haces referencia ?

Comment: Es el parametro que le tenes que pasar.

Comment: Cambie por param_fecha

Comment: Es un rango de fechas, no una fecha en particular. Si hay coincidencia entre los rangos no podrias hacer la insercion

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que lo que precisas es saber al momento de ingresar un evento si el `responsable` ya tiene asignado otro evento en el rango de fechas entre `start` y `end`

De ser asi, lo que podrías hacer es consultar previo a la inserción de una tupla en event de la siguiente manera:

Asumiendo que en tu aplicacion al momento de realizar este chequeo tienes 3 variables con los valores a consultar

`param_start` fecha de inicio del periodo del nuevo evento a insertar

`param_end` fecha de fin del periodo del nuevo evento a insertar`

`param_responsable` identificador del responsable del cual se quiere insertar un nuevo evento

```
select 1 from event where idresponsable = param_responsable and ((start between param_start and param_end) or (end between param_start and param_end))
```

De esta manera si esta consulta arroja resultados significa que el responsable tiene un evento tal que alguna de las fechas de inicio o fin del nuevo evento a insertar caen dentro del rango del evento anterior, lo cual haria imposible su presencia.

Comment: La consulta me funciona, tengo otro problema ahora, ¿cómo tendría que hacer para poder hacer que la consulta también tome en cuenta la hora?.

Comment: Kevin, si te fue util la respuesta te agradezco si la valoras positivamente. Eso se hace clickeando la flecha hacia arriba a la izquierda de la respuesta.
Supongo que tus fechas son del tipo DATETIME, en ese caso lo unico que tienes que hacer es utilizar el mismo formato que en tu insercion. Es decir, si estas insertando las fechas con el formato "dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss" tus param_start y param_end deberian ser del estilo '28/05/2017 12:00:00'